# Webservice to access SQL Server 2012 database

Tags: sql, web-services, iis

I have a SQL Server 2012 with a database on it. I need to publish that information in the database as a web service.

Not done this before so anyone got any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

All i need to do is select the information not update or delete

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use SqlConnection and SqlCommand class to connect with the database, and for the webservice you can chose if you want WCF or asmx, or other service. 
Next time, please take a look here > [How to ask on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try with managed data services configuration manager and select web configuration.